# Snowflake SQL - OBJECT_CONSTRUCT from COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to summarize data in a table:

- counting total rows
- counting values on specific fields
- getting the distinct values on specific fields

and, more importantly, I'm struggling with:

- getting the count for each field nested in an object

given this data

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| null | 1 |
| B | null |
| B | null |

the expected result from this query would be:

```sql
with dummy as (
select 'A' as col1, 0 as col2
union all
select null, 1
union all
select 'B', null
union all
select 'B', null
)

select
    count(1) as total
    ,count(col1) as col1
    ,array_agg(distinct col1) as dist_col1
    --,object_construct(???) as col1_object_count
    ,count(col2) as col2
    ,array_agg(distinct col2) as dist_col2
    --,object_construct(???) as col2_object_count
from
    dummy
```

| TOTAL | COL1 | DIST_COL1 | COL1_OBJECT_COUNT | COL2 | DIST_COL2 | COL2_OBJECT_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | ["A", "B"] | {"A": 1, "B", 2, null: 1} | 2 | [0, 1] | {0: 1, 1: 1, null: 2} |

I've tried several functions inside `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` mixed with `ARRAY_AGG`, but all failed

- `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` can work with several columns but only given all (`*`), if you try a select statement inside, it will fail
- another issue is that analytical functions are not easily taken by the object or array functions in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html#snowflake-scripting) or [Snowpark](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/index.html) for this but here's a solution that is somewhat flexible so you can apply it to different tables and column sets.

Create test table/view:

```
Create or Replace View dummy as (
   select 'A' as col1, 0 as col2
   union all
   select null, 1
   union all
   select 'B', null
   union all
   select 'B', null
);
```

Set session variables for table and colnames.

```
set tbname = 'DUMMY';
set colnames = '["COL1", "COL2"]';
```

Create  view that generates the required table_column_summary data:

```
Create or replace View table_column_summary as 
   with
   -- Create table of required column names
   cn as (
      select VALUE::VARCHAR CNAME 
      from table(flatten(input => parse_json($colnames)))
         )
   -- Convert rows into objects
   ,ro as (
      select
         object_construct_keep_null(*) row_object
   -- using identifier on session variable to dynamically supply table/view name
      from identifier($tbname) )  
   -- Flatten row objects into key/values 
   ,rof as (   
      select  
            key col_name,
            ifnull(value,'null')::VARCHAR col_value
      from ro, lateral flatten(input => row_object), cn
      -- You will only need this filter if you need a subset
      -- of columns from the source table/query summarised
      where col_name = cn.cname)
   -- Get the column value distinct value counts
   ,cdv as (
      select col_name,
             col_value,
             sum(1) col_value_count 
      from rof
      group by 1,2 
   )
   -- and derive required column level stats and combine with cdv   
   ,cv as (   
      select
        (select count(1) from dummy) total,
        col_name,
        object_construct('COL_COUNT', count(col_value) , 
                         'COL_DIST',  array_agg(distinct col_value), 
                         'COL_OBJECT_COUNT', object_agg(col_value,col_value_count)) col_values  
      from cdv
      group by 1,2)
-- Return result
Select * from cv;
```

Use this final query if you want a solution that works flexibility with any table/columns provided as input...

```
Select total, object_agg(col_name, col_values) col_values_obj
From table_column_summary
Group by 1;
```

Or use this final query if you want the fixed columns output as described in your question...

```
Select total, 
        COL1[0]:COL_COUNT COL1, 
        COL1[0]:COL_DIST DIST_COL1, 
        COL1[0]:COL_OBJECT_COUNT COL1_OBJECT_COUNT, 
        COL2[0]:COL_COUNT COL2, 
        COL2[0]:COL_DIST DIST_COL2, 
        COL2[0]:COL_OBJECT_COUNT COL2_OBJECT_COUNT
from table_column_summary 
   PIVOT ( ARRAY_AGG ( col_values ) 
            FOR col_name IN ( 'COL1', 'COL2' ) ) as pt (total, col1, col2);
```